# Hide confidential data from sql server

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am working on company's confidential data. Is there any way we can hide this data from back-end and still can see from front-end application? User will have access to database and tables but can't see the data.

Comment: You can handle this with database permissions.

Comment: Hide data from back-end and still see from front-end is inconsistent with user will have access to the database and tables but can't see the data.  The database is the back end.  Clarify what you want to hide and from whom.

Answer (score 2):

Some hints:

1. Handle permissions by restricting the access to the sensitive data to a single user.
2. Add encryption.

   Note that some information, such as the passwords of the users, should be salted and hashed, instead of being simply encrypted. The difference is that en encrypted piece of data can be decrypted using a private key or a password. Data which is salted and hashed cannot be decrypted (while is still sensitive to brute force attacks).
3. Handle permissions **and** add encryption.
4. Remove the data from the database machine and move it to a safer place (for example if the SQL server is collocated for several projects and is accessed by many developers, while the app server is only accessed by a few trusted persons, moving the data to the app server might improve the security a little). This shouldn't prevent you to add permissions and encryption.
5. Don't store the data in the first place.

   For example, instead of storing passwords of the users, you may use OpenID, and let Google and other companies deal with security. Instead of storing credit card information of your customers, you can use services of other companies such as PayPal in order to be sure that you never get credit card numbers in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are many tips to hide data in SQL Server.
One of them is Database Views.
Create different views on different table base on your limited column of table and assign only select permission on that particular views. 
Don’t provide a any grant on any tables. 
I hope, this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the sensitive data, so it will be stored in the database in an encoded form and being decoded upon retrieval.